# apparently ran_num is not defined

Tags: python

So I've remade part of my dicegame's code and it's works somewhat decently, however after ROLL'ing the dice and attempting to display the users score, I run in to an error where is says 'name p1_score is not defined'. It says the same thing for the variable p2_score aswell. However I defined p1_score as ran_num+ran_num so I don't get why I'm getting an error.

```
import random
import time

player_1 = input("")
player_2 = input("")

def rollDice(player_1):
        ran_num = random.randint(1,6)
        if ran_num == 1:
            print("You rolled a",ran_num)
        else:
            print("You rolled a",ran_num)
        p1_score = ran_num+ran_num


def rollDice(player_2):
        ran_num = random.randint(1,6)
        if ran_num == 1:
            print("You rolled a",ran_num)
        else:
            print("You rolled a",ran_num)
        p2_score = ran_num+ran_num


print("Please press ENTER to roll the dice")
input()
rollDice(player_1)
print("Good job",player_1,)
print("Your score is now",p1_score)
time.sleep(5)
print(player_2,"Press ENTER to roll the dice")
input()
rollDice(player_2)
print("Nice work",player_2)
print("Your score is now",p2_score)

def main():
    rollDice(player1, player2)

main()
```

Comment: Those variables are local to the function. You need to return them to the code that calls it.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that?

Comment: Do you know what `return` does?

Comment: Somewhat, I'm extremely new to python and this was for my highschool computing class.

Comment: Definitely look up what `return` does, and practice using it. It's extremely important. Long story short, your problem is that since you defined those variables in the function, they're only available in the function. You need to return them from the function to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variable scoping issue, you either need to use a global (globals can be dangerous if used incorrectly) the same way you have with player_1 and player_2, OR return from that function and use the returned value for the output.

http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

"Not affiliated with that website, just did a quick google to see if I could find a resource for you to read so you can understand"

```
import random
import time

def rollDice():
    ran_num = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled a " + str(ran_num))
    raw_input()
    resolved_score = ran_num+ran_num
    return str(resolved_score)

player_1 = raw_input("Enter player one name: ")
player_2 = raw_input("Enter player two name: ")

print("Please press ENTER to roll the dice")
raw_input()
p1_result = rollDice()

print("Good job "+player_1)
print("Your score is now "+p1_result)
time.sleep(5)

print(player_2+" Press ENTER to roll the dice")
raw_input()
p2_result = rollDice()

print("Nice work "+player_2)
print("Your score is now "+p2_result)
```

I've rationalised your code a bit, there were some logic errors. Notice in the def I have a return statement, the return statement adds two numbers together, converts it to a string using str() and I use RETURN to spit the value back out to the calling code. In this case the calling code is first encountered where we see:

```
p1_result = rollDice()
```

Now p1_result will equal whatever the ran_num+ran_num resolved to inside the function.

Comment: **BUT** never prefer globals unless the alternative is *really* messy. Prefer returning whenever possible.

Comment: Agreed, he seems confused over what a "return" statement actually is though, so I might have to write up an example for him.

Comment: If you could give me an example that'd be great :)

Comment: Hello, are you still there?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got majority of it to work but it just multiplies the number that the player rolled instead of adding it on to the previous number the player rolled if you get what I mean.